# Crystal report is not shown in vs ultimate 2010 solution

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have web application form  and want to generate Crystal reports. I have downloaded CRforVS_13_0.exe for window 7 64 bit.. Crystal report of SAP and Installed, in tool box crystalreportviewer is available ... but my problem is that i cant view crystal report icon to make report 
As right click properties of  web project  -> add new item ->  (here i cant find any crystal report icon )

my target frame work is "Target Framework from ".Net Framework 4.0 " and i have add all the crystal report reference dll in web application project.

Problem :

I can't view crystal report icon to make report
Please help me to overcome on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I FIND SOLUTION VIA INSTALLING THIS http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe
AFTER THIS I CAN GENEREATE REPORTS